# How to build from source when there's no configure file

Tags: linux, build

Usually I start with `./configure`, but there's no configure file supplied. 
These are the directory contents:

```
autogen.sh      configure.ac  GNUmakefile.am  Makefile.shared  Source  WebKitLibraries  wscript
CMakeLists.txt  Examples      Makefile        ManualTests      Tools   WebKit.pro
```

How do I build this? Am I supposed to run `autogen.sh`? I tried that, and this was the result:

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal -I Source/autotools 
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --install --copy
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in AC_CONFIG_AUX_DIR, `Source/autotools'.
libtoolize: copying file `Source/autotools/config.guess'
libtoolize: copying file `Source/autotools/config.sub'
libtoolize: copying file `Source/autotools/install-sh'
libtoolize: copying file `Source/autotools/ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIR, `Source/autotools'.
libtoolize: copying file `Source/autotools/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `Source/autotools/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `Source/autotools/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `Source/autotools/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file `Source/autotools/lt~obsolete.m4'
libtoolize: Consider adding `-I Source/autotools' to ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS in Makefile.am.
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --include=Source/autotools
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --include=Source/autotools
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --no-force
configure.ac:81: installing `Source/autotools/compile'
configure.ac:41: installing `Source/autotools/missing'
Tools/GNUmakefile.am:285: ENABLE_GTK_DOC does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL
GNUmakefile.am:235:   `Tools/GNUmakefile.am' included from here
GNUmakefile.am: installing `Source/autotools/depcomp'
autoreconf: automake failed with exit status: 1
```

What happened?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this project uses cmake; try:

```
 mkdir build
 cd build
 cmake ..
```